# How to "or" all elements in the range of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

I am trying to say `if x == consonants[0] or [1] or [2]` all the way to `[21]` on one line.  For some reason I thought `consonants[0..21]` would work but it doesn't:

```
consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
new_first = ["m", "a", "t", "t", "h", "e", "w", "s"]


new_first.each do |x|
if x == consonants[0]
    puts x.next!
elsif x == consonants[1]
    puts x.next!
elsif x == consonants[2]
    puts x.next!
elsif x == consonants[3]
    puts x.next!    
else
    puts "test failed"
end

end
```

Comment: Your code implies that your question is, "I would like to replace each element `x` of `new_first` that is a consonant with `x.next`". In any event, you need to edit to state your question.  Readers may wonder about `"z"` (even though it's not an element of `new_first`), as `z.next #=> "aa"`, not `"a"`. You should clarify that as well.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code you've written, we need to know the expected output in addition to the minimal input and your test code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several ways to crack this nut, but it depends on your performance concerns, and how extensible this needs to be. Normally a chain of `if` statements which are of the form `x == y` and `x == z` can be folded into:

```
 case (x)
 when y, z
   # ... Executed on a match
 end
```

In your case you can even do this by using your array as a list of valid values:

```
 case (x)
 when *constants
   puts x.next!
 end
```

For larger lists you might want to fold this up into a Set since these are optimized for `include?` tests:

```
consonants_set = Set.new(consonants)

if (consonants_set.include?(x))
  puts x.next!
end
```

Since you're doing single letter matches you have a lot more options. For example, a regular expression:

```
consonants_regexp = Regexp.new('[%s]' % consonants.join)

if (consonants_regexp.match(x))
  puts x.next!
end
```

Or you can even do a simple substring match:

```
consonants_string = consonants.join

if (consonants_string[x])
  puts x.next!
end
```

Worth noting but you can iterate over the characters in strings:

```
'cwzbrly'.each_char do |c|
  puts c
end
```

That avoids the need to create and/or type in long arrays of the form `[ 'a', 'b', ... ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if consonants.include? (x)
     your-code-here
end
```

This will check if there's an element equal to x inside the array.

Comment: awesome!  perfect.  Thanks dude!

Comment: No worries, my pleasure!

Comment: actually, what if I need to consonants to move to the next consonant instead of the next letter in the alphabet?

Comment: right now it is taking the "t", recognizing it is in the consonants array and replacing it with a "u" because I am using .next!  Should I be using something else?

Comment: In that case, you can say x = consonants[consonants.index(x) + 1]. This will return the element at the index right after the index of x.

Comment: `x = consonants[consonants.index(x) + 1]` is going to have a problem if the consonant was "z".

Comment: ^ True dat, in that case you'll have to put an if-statement to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
if x =~ /[aeiou]/
  puts 'test failed'
else
  puts x.next!    
end
```

`/[aeiou]/` is saying match anything that is a, e, i, o, or u.

This will eliminate the need to create an array of consonants.

Comment: yes but my goal is to change the constonant to the next consonant and the vowel to the next vowel for the arraynew_first = ["m", "a",

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand and you're expecting `nuuixt` as a result, you can do:

```
new_first.select { |letter| consonants.include?(letter) && letter.next! }
```

`&&` works here this way: if `consonants.include?(letter)` evaluates to true then block return `letter.next!` .

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
consonants = ('a' .. 'z').to_a - %w[a e i o u] # => ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
shifted_consonants = consonants.zip(consonants.rotate).to_h # => {"b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h", "h"=>"j", "j"=>"k", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s", "s"=>"t", "t"=>"v", "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"b"}
'matthews'.chars.map{ |c| shifted_consonants[c] || c } # => ["n", "a", "v", "v", "j", "e", "x", "t"]
```

That took the range of `'a'` to `'z'` and converted it to an array, then subtracted the array of vowels, resulting in only consonants.

Next, it turned the array of consonants into a hash/look-up table `shifted_consonants` where each key is a current consonant and the value is the next consonant.

Finally, it takes each character in `'matthews'` and looks to see if there is a value in `shifted_consonants` for that character. If not, `nil` is returned, which triggers `||` and returns the current character. If there is a hit in the hash, the next value for that consonant is returned, which short-circuits the `||` "or".

An alternate would be to take advantage of `tr`:

```
consonants = (('a' .. 'z').to_a - %w[a e i o u]).join # => "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
shifted_consonants = consonants.chars.rotate.join # => "cdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb"
'matthews'.tr(consonants, shifted_consonants).chars # => ["n", "a", "v", "v", "j", "e", "x", "t"]
```

Checking for speed:

```
CONSONANTS = ('a' .. 'z').to_a - %w[a e i o u] # => ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_HASH = CONSONANTS.zip(CONSONANTS.rotate).to_h # => {"b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h", "h"=>"j", "j"=>"k", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s", "s"=>"t", "t"=>"v", "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"b"}

CONSONANTS_STR = (('a' .. 'z').to_a - %w[a e i o u]).join # => "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_STR = CONSONANTS_STR.chars.rotate.join # => "cdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb"

require 'fruity'

sample_string = 'matthews'
compare  do
  use_hash { sample_string.chars.map{ |c| SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_HASH[c] || c } }
  use_tr { sample_string.tr(CONSONANTS_STR, SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_STR).chars }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> use_tr is faster than use_hash by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

The longer the sample string is, the greater the difference. Changing to:

```
sample_string = 'matthews' * 1000
```

I see a result of:

```
# >> Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> use_tr is faster than use_hash by 4x ± 0.1
```

---

Found in a comment, *NOT* in the question where it belongs...

> my goal is to change the constonant to the next consonant and the vowel to the next vowel for the arraynew_first = ["m", "a",

Adjusting for that here's some changes. You can unravel the deltas:

```
ALPHABET = ('a' .. 'z').to_a
VOWELS = %w[a e i o u]
CONSONANTS = ALPHABET - VOWELS # => ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

SHIFTED_CONSONANTS = CONSONANTS.rotate # => ["c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "b"]
SHIFTED_VOWELS = VOWELS.rotate # => ["e", "i", "o", "u", "a"]

SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_HASH = CONSONANTS.zip(SHIFTED_CONSONANTS).to_h # => {"b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h", "h"=>"j", "j"=>"k", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s", "s"=>"t", "t"=>"v", "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"b"}
SHIFTED_VOWELS_HASH = VOWELS.zip(SHIFTED_VOWELS).to_h # => {"a"=>"e", "e"=>"i", "i"=>"o", "o"=>"u", "u"=>"a"}

sample_string = 'matthews'

sample_string.chars.map{ |c| SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_HASH[c] || SHIFTED_VOWELS_HASH[c] } # => ["n", "e", "v", "v", "j", "i", "x", "t"]


CONSONANTS_STR = CONSONANTS.join # => "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_STR = SHIFTED_CONSONANTS.join # => "cdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb"
SHIFTED_VOWELS_STR = SHIFTED_VOWELS.join # => "eioua"
CHARACTERS_STR = (CONSONANTS + VOWELS).join # => "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzaeiou"
SHIFTED_CHARACTERS_STR = SHIFTED_CONSONANTS_STR + SHIFTED_VOWELS_STR # => "cdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzbeioua"

sample_string.tr(CHARACTERS_STR, SHIFTED_CHARACTERS_STR).chars # => ["n", "e", "v", "v", "j", "i", "x", "t"]
```

The changes won't affect the speed of the actual code: `tr` would still outrun using the hash lookups.